# python reverse byteorder from network service

Tags: python, networking

I get the following bytes from a network service: `\x83\x08\x04\x04\x60\x02\x00\x81\x15\x01\x01` These are 8 bit number. I want to change the representation to my system's representation (32 bits) to be able to work on the bytes. How would I do this with python? Is there a special 'reverse' function for this?

best regards

Comment: How are those bytes supposed to be interpreted?

Comment: Okay, the bytes are clear now. Now you need to say whether these are 16-bit, 32-bit or 64-bit numbers, or even something else.

Comment: You want to group 11 bytes into groups of 4? How is that supposed to work?

Comment: No, maybe my understanding is wrong. But all I want to do is transform the big-endian to little endian. So I would still have 11 bytes at the end but the written down the other way

Comment: Steve, if you have list of 1-byte integers, endianness is irrelevant. You can simply convert them to unsigned integers using `map(ord, data)` or `map(ord, reversed(data)`, depends if you want to precess them backwards or what. See my answer for using `struct`, but note that providing `!11b` to `struct.unpack` won't reverse order of your bytes in string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have 8-bit numbers the byte order is irrelevant, as there is only one byte in each of them. If you want to convert every character to integer you can write:

```
struct.unpack("11B", "\x83\x08\x04\x04\x60\x02\x00\x81\x15\x01\x01")
```

or

```
struct.unpack("!11B", "\x83\x08\x04\x04\x60\x02\x00\x81\x15\x01\x01")
```

or

```
map(ord, "\x83\x08\x04\x04\x60\x02\x00\x81\x15\x01\x01")
```

It's equivalent. 
If string contains 16-bit or 32-bit integers, you can write things like:

```
struct.unpack("!IIHB", "\x83\x08\x04\x04\x60\x02\x00\x81\x15\x01\x01")
```

which would be decoded as two 4-byte, one 2-byte and one 1-byte unsigned integers. The `!` (which is equivalent to big-endian `>`) means that string is in network byte order, so all integers larger than one byte can be converted correctly to your native byte order.

**EDIT:** If what you want is to get eleven numbers and process them in reversed order, you should use one of above methods and call `reversed`, for example: `reversed(map(ord, data))`; but this reverses the order regardless of your native byte order. You didn't say what the data really is thou and I'm not convinced endianness does matter here.

Answer (score 1):

Determine which byte order the bytes are in, and supply the correct [byte order character](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment) to `struct.unpack`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reverse all of the bytes in a string, you can do this:

```
'example string'[::-1]
```

I would recommend the [struct](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html) module for unpacking network or otherwise binary data, as you otherwise don't have a good way to tell where exactly the reversing needs to happen. It allows you to specify the byte order.

Comment: Reversing a string can be done a bit simpler: `"mystring"[::-1]`

Comment: you're right, wasn't thinking of slices (which are super fast)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by `8308040460020081150101`, but the [`struct`](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html) package should have everything you need.

Comment: Oh sry I fixed the initial post.

Comment: How would I use that? I tried: `print struct.unpack('!b', '\x83\x08\x04\x04\x60\x02\x00\x81\x15\x01\x01')` but doesen't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the core [struct](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html) library?  It has methods for converting byte orders.